# Unable to get info from JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson

I have a problem trying to access some information in a JsonNode. Basically, I have:

```
getResponse(String response) {
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response);

System.out.println("rootNode.asText(): " + rootNode.asText());
// OUTPUT: {"statusCode":2,"message":"[701] - [FAILED - There was an error while calling OSB - Connection refused]"}
System.out.println("rootNode.toString(): " + rootNode.toString());
// OUTPUT: "{\"statusCode\":2,\"message\":\"[701] - [FAILED - There was an error while calling OSB - Connection refused]\"}"
System.out.println("rootNode.textValue(): " + rootNode.textValue());
// OUTPUT: {"statusCode":2,"message":"[701] - [FAILED - There was an error while calling OSB - Connection refused]"}
System.out.println("rootNode.findValue(statusCode): " + rootNode.findValue("statusCode"));
// OUTPUT: null
System.out.println("rootNode.get(statusCode).asText(): " + rootNode.get("statusCode"));
// OUTPUT: null
System.out.println("rootNode.get(statusCode).asText(): " + rootNode.get("statusCode").asText());
// OUTPUT: npe
}
```

basically, i'm trying to get the statusCode and message values that are in the response string.

Comment: Can you print "response" (the string variable) too?

Comment: Hi @HalilİbrahimBinol here it is:
System.out.println("response: " + response);
// OUTPUT: response: "{\"statusCode\":0,\"message\":\"[0000] - [OK]\"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment I assume your `response` variable contains unusual json data.

I try to unescape json;

```
    String response = "\"{\\\"statusCode\\\":0,\\\"message\\\":\\\"[0000] - [OK]\\\"}\"";

    System.out.println("Unwanted json string: " + response);
    // output is "{\"statusCode\":0,\"message\":\"[0000] - [OK]\"}"
    // this is exactly the same what you comment
    response = response.substring(1, response.length() - 1);
    response = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(response);
    // org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
    System.out.println("Unescaped json string: " + response);
    // output is {"statusCode":0,"message":"[0000] - [OK]"}

    JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response);

    System.out.println(rootNode.get("statusCode")); // will print 0
    System.out.println(rootNode.get("message")); // will print "[0000] - [OK]"
```

The best option is investigate why you are getting wrong json data. It's valid json but not you want for. You might be sent it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, dude.
I got solved yesterday by doing this (also I created a new class):

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(response);
submitTransactionResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(rootNode.asText(), SubmitTransactionResponse.class);
System.out.println(submitTransactionResponse.getStatusCode()); // print 0
System.out.println(submitTransactionResponse.getMessage()); // print "[0000] - [OK]"
```